# How do I do populate on mongoosastic?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, mongoose, mongoosastic

My goal is to populate certain fields in mongoosastic search, but if I do the following codes, it will always return

[image]

Here's the code

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Category = require('./category');
var mongoosastic = require('mongoosastic');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ProductSchema = new Schema({
  category: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category', es_schema: Category, es_indexed:true, es_select: 'name'},
  name: String,
  price: Number,
  image: String
});

ProductSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
  hosts: [
    'localhost:9200'
  ],
  populate: [
    {path: 'category', select: 'name'}
  ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);


var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var CategorySchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);
```

api.js

```
router.post('/search', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body.search_term);
  Product.search({
    query_string: { query: req.body.search_term }
  }, function(err, results) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(results);
  });
});
```

What should I do to populate a certain category in mongoosastic?

Comment: Did you get this to work? I have a similar issue where I get 0 hits when populating. I've read over the docs numerous time, but I'm not sure where I went wrong. If you could provide insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37758652/mongoosastic-elastic-search-will-not-return-any-hits-when-populating

Comment: are you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
populate: [
  {path: 'categories', select: 'name'}
]
```

But `categories` in your code is `undefined`.

> You have to use **category in the place of `categories`** as you have
>   mentioned the key as category in the schema declaration

Hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Edit:

```
category: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category', es_schema: Category, es_indexed:true, es_select: 'name'},
```

=> `_category : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' },`

And use populate: `.populate('_category ', 'name')`

Hope it will help you.

See more: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: This is only for mongoose, Im talking about mongoosastic.