# Why is mongoosastic populate / elastic search not populating one of my references? I'm getting an empty object

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, mongoose, mongoosastic

I have two models I'm attempting to reference. Style and Brand.

Brand populates with the needed object, but Style is always empty.

i've tried clearing cache / deleting indexes. With and without include_in_parent and type: 'nested'.

I feel it may have something to do with the specified es_type, etc.. not sure.

---

Product Schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var Style = require('./style');
    var Brand = require('./brand');
    var mongoosastic = require('mongoosastic');


    var ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      name: { type: String, lowercase: true , required: true},
      brand: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Brand',
             es_type:'nested', es_include_in_parent:true},
        style: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Style',
            es_schema: Style, es_type:'nested', es_include_in_parent: true},    
            year: { type: Number }
    });

    ProductSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
      hosts: [
        'localhost:9200'
      ],
      populate: [
        {path: 'style'},
        {path: 'brand'}
      ]
    });

    Product = module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);

    Product.createMapping(function (err,mapping) {
        if(err){
        console.log('error creating mapping (you can safely ignore this)');
        console.log(err);
      }else{
        console.log('product mapping created!');
        console.log(mapping);
        }
    });

    var stream = Product.synchronize();
    var count = 0;

    stream.on('data', function(){
      count++
    });

    stream.on('close', function(){
      console.log('indexed whisks ' + count + " documents");
    });

    stream.on('error', function(){
    });
```

style schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var mongoosastic = require('mongoosastic');

var StyleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, lowercase: true , required: true},
});

Style = module.exports = mongoose.model('Style', StyleSchema);

Style.createMapping(function(err, mapping){
  if(err) console.log('error w/ mapping : ', err);
  console.log('mapping created');
  console.log(mapping);
})

var stream = Style.synchronize();
var count = 0;

stream.on('data', function(){
  count++
});

stream.on('close', function(){
  console.log('indexed styles ' + count + " documents");
});

stream.on('error', function(){
});
```

search query:

```
    exports.topSearch = function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body, "search product")
  Product.search({query_string: {query: req.body.search}}, {from: req.body.fromNum,
        size: req.body.size,
        hydrate: req.body.hydrate
    },
    function(err, results) {
      if (err) console.log('ERR', err);
      if (results){
      var data = results.hits.hits.map(function(hit) {
        return hit
      });
      console.log('product data', data)
      res.send(data);
    }
    else {
      res.send({errmsg:'results not defined'})
    }
    });
};
```

When I query, I get this result in a hit:

```
_source:
 { name: 'Redemption White Rye Whiskey',
   brand: [Object],
   style: {},} },
```

---

---

regarding comment request:

Product being added to DB:

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
  Product.create(req.body, function(err, product) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('ERR', err)
    };
    res.send({
      product: product
    });
  });
};
```

front / angular:

```
  $scope.add = function () {
    var prodStyle = JSON.parse($scope.selectedStyle);
    $scope.product = $scope.product._id;
    $scope.product.style = prodStyle._id;
    console.log($scope.product.style, 'prod style');
    Product.create($scope.product).then(function (res) {
      res.data.product.style = { name: prodStyle.name };
      $scope.products.push(res.data.product);
      $scope.product = {};
      $scope.selectedStyle = {};
    });
  };
```

Comment: Can you post the code you use to submit the document?

Comment: for the elasticsearch / mongoosastic query, or how I add the Product?  I've added the query and some additional information.

Comment: Sorry I meant adding the product

Comment: I can.  The correct object ID is assigned, and I'm able to use the standard mongoose Model.populate. But, if it helps -- sure thing.

Comment: Let me know if that's what you're looking for or if any more detail may be needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got it working, but it differs much from the examples given on npm / github.

I had to remove the es_schema: Style, (as I had accidentally done for brand, which was why it worked). I had to add the es_type: "nested" / es_include_in_parent, which I gathered from elasticsearch and mongoosastic documentation.

I'm not sure this is intended, but it seems to work:

```
style: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Style',
    es_type:'nested', es_include_in_parent:true},
```

I now get :  style: [Object] as needed, when I console.log results.hits .

---

Below is the example given in npm , which did not work for me:

```
var Comment = new Schema({
    title: String
  , body: String
  , author: String
});


var User = new Schema({
    name: {type:String, es_indexed:true}
  , email: String
  , city: String
  , comments: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment',
    es_schema: Comment, es_indexed:true, es_select: 'title body'}
})

User.plugin(mongoosastic, {
  populate: [
    {path: 'comments', select: 'title body'}
  ]
})
```